# does Azure Databricks log run info for child notebooks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-log-analytics

I am working in Azure Databricks.  I have a notebook (say, A) that runs another notebook (say, B).  Where does the run info for notebook B get logged to, either in Databricks or in Log Analytics?  I have checked Databricks (Workflows \ Job runs), but I don't see a log in there for this notebook.  I also checked Log Analytics (in table DatabricksJobs), but I don't see it in there either.  I see the log for the parent notebook (notebook A) in both Databricks and in Log Analytics, but I don't see a log for the child notebook (notebook B) in either tool.  I am beginning to think that child notebook run info doesn't get logged.

Comment: how do you run it? `%run` or `dbutils.notebook.run` ?

Comment: Some child notebooks get ran via %run.  Others are ran via dbutils.notebook.run, which I believe creates a new job.  I haven't looked for the jobs in DatabricksJobs that are ran via dbutils.notebook.run, but I'm sure they're there.  But, does %run log anything?  If so, where does it go?

Comment: No, `%run` shouldn't be logged... It's really similar to the `#include` in C/C++

Comment: Oh dang.  I was fearing you might say that.